# Logout from your CMS to avoid session conflicts

Tags: wordpress

I'm following this [guide](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Contributing+to+CiviCRM+using+GitHub). After I did `gitify wordpress --hooks` and followed the instruction to fill up `setup.conf` file. Then I did `./setup.sh -Dg` as prompted and this is when I get error - `NOTE: Logout from your CMS to avoid session conflicts.`

I tried logging out from my wordpress local admin account, but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: gitify is a deprecated approach to setting up a development environment.  You may have better luck with civicrm-buildkit.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an error message. When the `setup.sh` script outputs "NOTE: Logout from your CMS to avoid session conflicts." then it has successfully completed. You may proceed to log in and begin using CiviCRM.